# How to determine which object emitted event, and get a reference in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, anonymous-function

So lets rewrite this to fit the correct answer I now remember asking however long ago.

Jfriend00's answer in the comments is correct.

Given the use case of an emitted event from an object that is derived from eventemitter

I wanted to know how to get a reference to the object itself.

So eg.

```
var myObj = new EmitterDescendent(); // some descendent of an emitter class
    myObj.name="123"; // some form of object tag.
myObj.on('eventofsomesort', ()=>
{
   var ref = (some manner of grabbing a reference to the object);
   console.log (ref.name);
});

// expected output: 123
```

Apparrently lambda screws up the 'this' keyword when the event handler is being called, I do not no why as using the function keyword should still be seen as an anonymous function.

Jfriend00's answer was what I was looking for.

Thanks very much.

Comment: You're completely misuing `Object`.  It doesn't have a `.on()` method.  You need to be using the `EventEmitter` object or some object that subclasses that object or some object that implements its interface.  Can you show your REAL code that is using streams so we can see exactly what you're trying to do rather than this misguided example code?

Comment: Stop using an `arrow` function for your callback. That is preventing you from using `this` inside the callback to identify which object emitted the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to ignore your example code using `Object` because there is no `.on()` method on `Object`.  That's a method that exists on the `EventEmitter` class.  Perhaps you didn't mean that to indicate the actual `Object` class in Javascript.

Assuming you had some code that was actually using an `EventEmitter`, a subclass of `EventEmitter` or some code that implements that interface, then if you declare your listener with a regular function, NOT with an arrow function, then the value of `this` will be the object that emitted the event.

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();

myEmitter.on("hi", function(data) {
    console.log(this === myEmitter);    // logs true
});

myEmitter.emit("hi", "hello");
```

Note, that in addition to using the value of `this`, if you're using an inline function declaration for the listener function, you also have direct access to the variable that you registered the event listener on.  In this case, it's the `myEmitter` variable.  If your listener is an external function, then that option is not available to you and you can use the value of `this`.  I remind you that you must register your listener as a regular function, not an arrow function because the arrow function overrides the value of `this`.

Here's a [doc reference](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_passing_arguments_and_this_to_listeners) to a discussion about using `this` in a listener.

Comment: not helpful, and no i didnt mean the actual object class. all that code does is check against a global variable already known.

Comment: @JohnSohn - Then, what the heck do you actually want?  Please show your REAL code and clarify your question.  Using `this` gets you the OBJECT THAT EMITTED THE EVENT.  I thought that's what you wanted to know.  Apparently your question is not clear.

Comment: @JohnSohn - Your latest edit says to your question that `this` is an empty object.  That is NOT true if you define your emitter callback as a regular function, NOT an arrow function.  You can see in MY example here that `this` is NOT an empty object.  It's the object that emitted the event.  You can use that if you fix your callback definition to a regular `function`, not an arrow function.

Comment: see updated answer. I figured using node.js people would understand I meant an object that includes events.  and why would I have difficulty checking an object against a global object ? and the previous unedited version mentions this is either empty or undefined.

Comment: @JohnSohn - Apparently you just don't understand what I'm recommending.  Fix your callback definition to use `function()`, not `() =>` and then `this` inside your callback will be the object that emitted the event.  My example `console.log(this === myEmitter); ` is just to show you what `this` is.  You do not have to use the `myEmitter` reference.  I'm just showing you that `this` is the desired value.

Comment: does node really not understand the difference between a lambda and an explicit function ? are you actually serious ?

Comment: @JohnSohn - The entire purpose of an arrow function is to OVERRIDE the value of `this` so that it will be the lexical value of `this`, not what the caller wanted `this` to be.  That's how they are designed.  They are NOT just a syntax shortcut - they have different behavior for the value of `this`.  That is a language feature that you have to know to use correctly.  You seem to be expecting Javascript to be something different than it is based on your experience with other languages.

Comment: Ah see that is confusing to someone used to C#.  Thanks very much.   Every example I am seeing is using this like an lambda shortcut for an anonymous function. So you know something they do not apparently.

Comment: @JohnSohn - Yeah, familiarity with other languages often leads to assumptions about a new language that are sometimes appropriate and sometimes not.  I learned Javascript coming from C++ and was regularly frustrated.  But, eventually I got use to Javascript as it is (with its advantages and its disadvantages).  Now, I very much enjoy programming in it.

Comment: I keep trying to upvote your answer and close the question ! And its not something which is exactly apparent :P  Like something I found in the request library in node js for example.

Comment: Dude its the site, I just selected your answer again and refreshed and now its gone !.

Comment: @JohnSohn - OK, my answer now shows as the selected answer.  I'm not sure what happened there.  Maybe it was a site glitch.  In case, you didn't realize, you don't need to "close" your question.   Once, you've indicated a selected answer with the checkmark by one of the answers, you're done.  That's the indication to the community that your question has been answered.  Once, you have earned more reputation, then you can "upvote" all answers that were helpful by clicking the up arrow.  But, you can only click one checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

This should be obvious. You already know which object emitted the event, because you registered an event handler on it. You should have tested your cod and would have found that `Object` doesn't have an `on` function:

```
> Object.on('event', console.log)
Uncaught TypeError: Object.on is not a function
```

Instead, in node.js you need to extend [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter), and then register listeners on the instance of that class. So you will know inside the handler who emitted the event.

```
EventEmitter = require('events');
e = new EventEmitter();
e.on('event', () => {
  console.log(e, 'emitted event');
});
e.emit('event');
```

Comment: no actually i don't.  the above was not a defacto example... so i suppose i will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your `Object` has extended from [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)  somehow. Nodejs `EventEmitter` events are not the same as HTML5 events. There's no `target` or `currentTarget` properties as the callback arguments are just the "raw" arguments passed in the `emit()` call.

You already have the object reference, and there are better ways of doing it, but if you really want to receive the object in the function callback, another way fo doing it, apart from using scopes and closures like the other answer, is to create a function with a [binded argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), like so (by the way, I personally prefer the scopes/closures one instead of the binding one):

```
Object.name="123";
Object.on('event', (function(ref) {
   console.log(ref.name);
}).bind(this, Object));
Object.emit('event');
```

You can even have the same function and bind it each time for each object, like so:

```
function funccallback(ref) {
    console.log(ref.name);
}

var object1 = {}; // Extend from "EventEmitter" somehow or it will not work
object1.name="123";
object1.on('event', funccallback.bind(this, object1));
object1.emit('event');

var object2 = {}; // Extend from "EventEmitter" somehow or it will not work
object2.name="124";
object2.on('event', funccallback.bind(this, object2));
object2.emit('event');
```